# Bayes Theorem P(A|D) =?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics

> What is the probability that A is true given that D is true
>
> [image: Probabilities of Events Graphs]
>   I'm mostly confused about applying Bayes' Theorem to event C

How can I use Bayes' Theorem to solve this?

Comment: Please try to write down the probabilities instead of linking an image.

Comment: I don't quite understand. What have you done so far? Formulae? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Sorry, I made the image, thinking that I'd be able to embed it but I don't have enough rep to do that apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we write down what we know.

We know $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(C \mid A, B)$, $P(D \mid C)$

We want to know $P(A \mid D)$

Now, $$P(A \mid  D) = \frac{P(D \mid A)P(A)}{P(D)}\tag{1}$$

where the denominator is a normalization factor: $P(D)=\sum_A {P(D \mid A)P(A)}$

Further, $$P(D \mid  A) = \sum_{B,C} P(B, C, D \mid A)\tag{2}
$$

and
$$P(B, C, D \mid A)=P(D \mid A,B,C) P(C,B \mid A)=P(D \mid A,B,C) P(C \mid A,B)P(B \mid A) \tag{3}$$

Then the numerator of $(1)$ is

$$\sum_{B,C} P(D \mid A,B,C) P(C \mid A,B)P(B \mid A) P(A) \tag{4}$$

Can we compute this? From the data given, we can't. We need the additional assumptions:

- $A,B$ are independent (hence $P(B \mid A)=P(B)$)
- $(A,B)\to C \to D$ form a Markov chain (informally, $C$ contains all the useful information in $(A,B,C)$ to predict $D$)

Under these (additional!) assumptions, $(4)$ simplifies to

$$\sum_{B,C} P(D \mid C) P(C \mid A,B)P(B) P(A) \tag{5}$$

which we can compute.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: And also your additional assumptions were correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are really $16$ possible outcomes here. To simplify notation, I'll use capital and lower-case letters, so $A=$"A is true", and $a=$"A is false".

The sixteen outcomes are thus: $ABCD, ABCd, \ldots, abcd$. Since we're working with the condition that $D$ is true, we're only interested in the $8$ possibilities with that condition, and we'll split them up according to whether $A$ is true:

Case 1: $ABCD \cup ABcD \cup AbCD \cup AbcD$

Case 2: $aBCD \cup aBcD \cup abCD \cup abcD$

The conditional probability you want is $\frac{P(\text{case} 1)}{P(\text{case} 1)+P(\text{case} 2)}$

As an example, $P(AbcD)=.05\times .80\times .10\times .001$

Does that give you enough of a push in the right direction?

Comment: There is no Bayes here , just a (fine) direct approach. Maybe the OP wanted something else?

Comment: Well, if you divide each term in that fraction by $P(A)$, then it becomes Bayes' formula, right?

Comment: Your example, it seems, comes from $P(AbcD)=P(D|c)P(c|bA)p(A)p(b)$ But this implies lot of things like $P(Ab)=P(A)P(b)$ that I don't see justified

Comment: Also: you are assuming $P(D|cbA)=P(D|c)$ (why?)

Comment: From the way the probabilities for $A$ and $B$ are given as absolutes, I assumed they were independent. Likewise, it appears that the probabilities for $D$ depend only on $C$. If those aren't true, then I'm not sure this question can be answered. Thus, I'm reasoning from the supposed answerability of the question.

Comment: Yes, your assumptions were correct A and B are independent and D depends only on C.

Comment: @Mike Actually $P(D|C,A,B)=P(D|C)$ doesn't imply (a common misconception) that "A and B are independent and D depends only on C". Actually, D has  a dependence on A,B. It's just that, _given C_ , then $D$ and $A,B$ are independent.

Comment: @leonbloy , the bit about A and B being independent was in response to your *first* comment

Comment: Sorry. Some confusion here, I should have quoted only the second half of the quote. My remark was not about $A$, $B$ being mutually independent (we all agree that that assumption is needed), but about the second half of Mike's sentence "$D$ depends only on $C$", which seems to imply that $D$ is independent of the pair $(A,B)$. This is neither true not necessary.

Comment: Yeah, the point is that $P(D|C)$ is well defined without having to talk about $P(D|C,A,B)$, etc.